# Global pdo connection not reachable in a PHPUnit Test

Tags: php, pdo, phpunit

I am start using PHPUnit for my projects and I need to test that some data is been stored successfully in the database.

My problem is that the PDO connection, which is created in a separate file with the name $connpdo, is not reachable. I really don't get why.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once("database_inc.php");

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

function save_twins($auto_id = 412184){
    global $connpdo;
    $query = "select quality_inspection from dqa_manifest_upload_rules where auto_id = $auto_id";
    $stmt = $connpdo->query($query);
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $quality = $row["quality_inspection"];
    return $quality;
}

class Test_save_twins extends TestCase
{
    public function testExamples()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('A', save_twins(412184));
    }
}
?>
```

The $connpdo variable is created in the file **database_inc.php**

```
$connpdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$cfgiDbHost;dbname=$cfgiDbDatabase;charset=utf8", $cfgiDbUser, $cfgiDbPasswd);
```

I have also tried without global but I don't know what happens. Maybe the use of the namespace?:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

I thought that maybe pdo was not enabled but I have checked with `php -m` and I see those modules:

```
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
Phar
```

Comment: I don't know really what is the problem, but I think you can use $GLOBALS['connpdo'] = $connpdo; in your database_inc.php file. I guess this will solve the problem and you'll have the variable as global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many months I understood that how PHPunit works. It won't read that include_once for the database if it's outside of the method. I moved it inside of the function and also I changed the phpUnit environment for a remote one, on the same server of the database, so the connection is allowed.

After those two changes my test is working:
https://www.screencast.com/t/O2ccmcxt2